# Can't decode HEVC video with DXVA2 and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I can't use DXVA2 hardware acceleration for decoding of HEVC video with ffmpeg. DXVA2 for H.264 works fine.

I compiled an official example hw_decode.c from ffmpeg sources:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c

When I call av_send_packet() it performs a callback assigned in AVCodecContext->get_format and returns only AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P for HEVC video instead of AV_PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD for all H.264 videos. So HW decoding doesn't work.

Software decoding of HEVC works without problems.

MPC-HC plays fine HEVC video with DXVA2 (CPU loading is low and Task Manager shows work of Video decoder in GPU details). My video card is Geforce 1060.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this by adding function :

```
  enum AVPixelFormat get_hw_format(AVCodecContext *ctx,
    const enum AVPixelFormat *pix_fmts)
   {
    return AV_PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD;
   }
```

Assigned adress of above function 
pCodecContext->get_format = get_hw_format;

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me. Decoding of HEVC fails.